# Window Authentication with seperate web server and database server

Tags: sql, asp.net, sql-server, webserver

What settings we need to do at server level in case we are using window authentication and our web server & database server are separate.

**Note:-** I am well aware about connection string setting in web.config file. The only concern is setting at database server level in case of window authentication.

Suggestions will be appreciated

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If you use windows authentication you just need to make sure that the user(s) under which your application runs also have access to the database(s) on the sql server. Using Management Studio you can add the windows logins or groups and grant them access.